# Field is required, but server side validation is not catching it

Tags: commerce

I have a multistep checkout form in my commerce module.  Inside Order Types i have added a field called Phone Number and set it to required.  And then I have a custom module which has a ContactInformation.php file under CheckoutPane which adds the field in buildPaneForm

```
    /**
 * Provides the contact information pane.
 *
 * @CommerceCheckoutPane(
 *   id = "contact_information",
 *   label = @Translation("<h2 tabindex='0'>Contact information</h2>"),
 *   default_step = "order_information",
 *   wrapper_element = "fieldset",
 * )
 */
class ContactInformation extends \Drupal\commerce_checkout\Plugin\Commerce\CheckoutPane\ContactInformation implements CheckoutPaneInterface {
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildPaneForm(array $pane_form, FormStateInterface $form_state, array &$complete_form) {
    $pane_form = parent::buildPaneForm($pane_form, $form_state, $complete_form);
    $form_builder = \Drupal::service('entity.form_builder');
    $order_form = $form_builder->getForm($this->order, 'default');
    $user_entry = $form_state->getUserInput();

    $pane_form['field_phone_number'] = $order_form['field_phone_number'];
    $pane_form['field_phone_number']['#weight'] = 99;

    if (isset($user_entry['field_phone_number'])) {
      $pane_form['field_phone_number']['widget'][0]['value']['#value'] = $user_entry['field_phone_number'][0]['value'];
    }

    return $pane_form;
  }
```

In my checkout form I am disabling HTML5 validation by setting $form['#attributes']['novalidate'] = 'novalidate';

Upon submitting the form without entering any data, the server side catches all the fields that are required but empty with a message saying the field is required (Email, First Name, Last Name, etc...).  All the fields except my Phone Number field.

In debug mode I see that the field has a key ['#required'] = true but the server side validation is not catching this field.

Any help would be appreciated.  Let me know if there's anything else you need that might help solve this issue.

Comment: I don't see any required attributes in your code.

Comment: When i created the field in the UI i selected Required.  I also checked in xDebug and required is set to true.  Also, I did try putting $pane_form['field_phone_number']['#required'] = true; in there as well to see if that would somehow solve the problem, but it did not.

Comment: You are setting the #value on the phone number. Change that to #default_value and see what happens.

Comment: I tried this and still the same outcome.

Comment: I am only setting the value if it exists.  If I remove that part completely then it is still the same.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not really something that can be debugged from the code you've shown. That was the only possibility I could see.

Comment: If there's anything else I can give you to help with this let me know.  It's really gotten me stumped

Comment: I'd guess it's because you're getting that field from another form, one that's already been built, and the elements have a `#processed` property which is stopping the current form builder from processing their validation properly